# how to link LMMS and Ardour5

Tags: ardour, lmms

My question is how do I  LMMS and Ardour5 singing?  My goal is to press play/record on Ardour and have LMMS start as well so I can record vocals on Ardour to the song I composed on LMMS.  I'm used to opening the beat machine as a vst in my multritracker but I cant seem to figure that out here in Linux land.

Answer (score 0):

As a very simple method, you can export a .wav file from Lmms and import that file as a track (or more tracks) in Ardour.  Then set your recording to an additional track in Ardour to get the vocals.

The Lmms track can be set to play through the system speakers while recording is happening on the vocal track, and you can set multiple vocal tracks to act as 'takes', so that you can chop up bits of the vocal tracks to get what you are looking for.

---

A much more complicated methos would be to utilize Jack to route the sound files being played by Lmms to the inputs of Ardour, but this would result in Ardour recording the Lmms tracks and the vocal tracks at the same time.

---

You *could* get Ardour to use the VSTs, directly.  I have not done that myself...

Comment: Thanks dude!  Could you explain utilizing Jack a bit.  I've dabbled in it but it's still over my head...